# Data Mining Minimum Support and Strong Association Rules

Tags: data-mining

If I have the following table:

[image: Transactions]

And if A = {I1}, B = {I2}, and I find the support is 0.4 and confidence is 0.5 for the association rule A ⇒ B, then how can I determine if this is a strong association rule or not?

For example, if minimum support is 30% then it'd be strong I imagine, correct? Because our support is 0.4 calculated. But if minimum support is 50%, then it isn't strong because we have less than that.

Am I correct in thinking like this in regards to the image I posted?

Comment: I strongly recommend the chi-square test for evaluating association rules.  This is explained in "Data Mining Techniques for Marketing, Sales, and Customer Support, Third Edition".

Comment: Define "strong". I only know "frequent", "maximal", "closed".

Answer (score 0):

Please read "Data Mining: Concepts and Techniques" written by J. Han, M. Kamber, and J. Pei.

Typically, an association rule is called strong if it satisfies both a minimum support threshold and a minimum confidence threshold that is determined by the user. In your case;

```
I1 ⇒ I2 [40%, 50%]
```

Using a minimum support of 30% and a minimum confidence of 60%, your association rule does not satisfy the minimum confidence threshold. Therefore, it's not a strong association rule.